# Can i post a helpful tip for other Communitys?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask something, I posted a question which a answered myself. The question was "What Online-Community Roles can I have/will be essential/needed?"(just my expression)
So I answered it myself cause this should be just like a Wiki-Article for Community-Admins who wants to improve their organization, etc...

Now I got a comment that I should write everything offline and then post it on SE(which would took me about 4-7 Days)... The reason why I did this(edit the Answer every single time) is that I don't have the time to do this(I work on different places with different machines and mostly I can't use a USB Drive) so I just could work on the post the most of the time.

When I'm not allowed to do this or this is against the rules, why is there no way to do something like that? Like a private Post, etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't want to rely on SE's save buffer; we don't know how long that lasts or what can clobber it.  IF you need to work on a post over time and from different machines, you might want to instead write it as a Google Doc or Gist.  I've used this approach, including when some amount of collaboration was required (site-policy posts).  You do have to write your Markdown "blind" (no preview there like here), so you should proofread before posting to SE, but most posts don't use a lot of special formatting, so this shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how long it lasts, but SE actually auto-saves drafts to your account.  I just tested it writing this post.  I started writing it, closed my browser, opened up another browser on a different machine and it was still there.  I don't recall if there is a timeout on that feature though and can't seem to find the meta post about when they introduced it anymore (it was about 6 to 12 months ago).

Ok, found some more details on the feature, technical details are available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature/111578#111578) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting).  Basically, it will save for 7 days associated to your user if you are registered or a cookie if you are anonymous, but only saves every minute or so.  There are also a number of situations in which it can be wiped.

Comment: Yeah i know the Feature but i think its just over the cookies. I wrote a post on my home Computer(i forgot to press the send button) and started a question on my workstation at my company but there was no saved text. If i work on the same machine it wouldn't be the problem but i'm switching constantly the Machines, etc...

Comment: I did it across systems and browsers (chrome on my server, firefox on my desktop) and it worked fine.  I updated my post with the links to more direct details on the feature.

Comment: Oh thank you :) I'll try it later :)